# Dynamically add Where clause to a query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to see if there is a way to dynamically add a where clause to the end of a query depending on certain criteria.

So let's say I have a query like this:

`let T = SomeTable | where x > 5 | where y <3`

But I don't always want that second where clause to be attached. I tried using IIF, but I don't think it works like that. It's weird though that you can't do something like this:

`let T = SomeTable  | where x > 5; iif(SomePredicate, T | where y < 3, null);`

I tried that, but it doesn't work. Is there something that can achieve that for me?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `or` operator with a boolean `condition_is_met` argument.

for example:

```
let T = range x from 1 to 10 step 1; // populate this as you wish
let condition_is_met = true;         // populate this as you wish
T
| where x > 5
| where condition_is_met or x < 8
```

| x |
| --- |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
| 10 |

same query, but with `condition_is_met = false`:

```
let T = range x from 1 to 10 step 1; // populate this as you wish
let condition_is_met = false;        // populate this as you wish
T
| where x > 5
| where condition_is_met or x < 8
```

| x |
| --- |
| 6 |
| 7 |

Comment: I don't even want the where clause in some cases. The "or" in my case is no where clause at all.

Comment: if you want the query to *_not_* include the `where` clause at all, then you will need to write code that dynamically generates the query text based on your conditional logic. the ADX cloud service *_can't_* currently write queries for you. it *_can_* execute queries you send to it